"AttributeError:module 'pkgutil' hasno attribute'ImpImporter'.Did you mean'zipimporter'?" Error while downloading requirements.txt
I am trying to follow along and replicate https://github.com/smaameri/youtube-chatbot this github repository, when following along, I first cloned the entire repository to my system as mentioned in the readme markdown, however, when I wanted to download all the dependencies and required libraries, I am getting the below error:
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [33 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File ".projectYTCB_venv\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File ".projectYTCB_venv\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File ".projectYTCB_venv\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 112, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          backend = _build_backend()
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File ".projectYTCB_venv\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 77, in _build_backend
          obj = import_module(mod_path)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File ".Python\Python312\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 90, in import_module
          return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1387, in _gcd_import
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1360, in _find_and_load
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1310, in _find_and_load_unlocked
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 488, in _call_with_frames_removed
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1387, in _gcd_import
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1360, in _find_and_load
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1331, in _find_and_load_unlocked
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 935, in _load_unlocked
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 995, in exec_module
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 488, in _call_with_frames_removed
        File ".Temp\pip-build-env-_vxs5bm0\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
          import setuptools.version
        File ".Temp\pip-build-env-_vxs5bm0\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\version.py", line 1, in <module>
          import pkg_resources
        File ".Temp\pip-build-env-_vxs5bm0\overlay\Lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2172, in <module>
          register_finder(pkgutil.ImpImporter, find_on_path)
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      AttributeError: module 'pkgutil' has no attribute 'ImpImporter'. Did you mean: 'zipimporter'?
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

What am I supposed to do to continue with this project, and how do I download the rest of the dependencies/libraries?
I have tried looking at other people who've had similar issues while downloading other libraries, I've gone through medium articles as well, all to no use, someone please help me.

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=AttributeError+%22module+pkgutil+has+no+attribute+ImpImporter%22
